# In this plunkr, why doesn't the ng-model update?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I forked a ui-select plunkr and adapted it to my own situation. The ng-model doesn't update, but clicking the button to update the model does update the ui-select.

Thanks in advance!

```
  <h3>Select2 theme</h3>
  <p>Selected: {{id}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="id" theme="select2" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.email}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person.id as person in people.devs | propsFilter: {email: $select.search, id: $select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.id | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        <span ng-bind-html="''+person.id | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        {{person.email}}
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-primary"ng-click="id = 2">Change Model</button>
  <span>(id = 2) </span>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3vEXkkNLvuNhpO1hKpmj?p=preview[enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vEXkkNLvuNhpO1hKpmj?p=preview)

Comment: because you always set it to 2 in `ng-click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem of scope :

```
 <ui-select ng-model="$parent.id" ....>
```

In order to never have this problem use dot notation and initialize variable in your controller : meaning intermediary fields.

```
 // controller
 $scope.context = {id:-1};
 // html
  <ui-select ng-model="context.id"
```

This happen quite often, `ng-if` will provoke the same problem. This is du to a limit of javascript inheritance. Angular can't help about it.

Comment: How did you find out? :)

Comment: Updated my plunker to use dot notation, (test.id). It works after clicking the button initially, but if I change the combobox initially it seems to break? http://plnkr.co/edit/3vEXkkNLvuNhpO1hKpmj?p=preview

Comment: Buecause there are quite some topics about problem with refresing models, it's a common issue so i always search for the $parent trick when i see that. For your plunkr, you forget the controller part : `$scope.test = {};` if you don't initialize it in your $scope's controller, it may end up in a child scope that some part of your template won't see.

Comment: Thank you so much!